# jQuery: Adding active class to sections when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my website made with divs, and I added the code below to scroll the page when clicking on the section name in the nav bar, and I added the code below to add the active class to the nav bar element when clicking on it, but I would like for the active class to be able to change on the navbar when I scroll through the page.

My code:

```
//Adding Active class to the active section in navi bar
  $('.navigationbar ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

  //Anchor scrolling animations
  var $root = $('html, body');
  $('.anchor').click(function() {
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML code for the div structures.

Comment: Check https://css-tricks.com/aos-css-driven-scroll-animation-library/

Comment: Here it is: https://codepen.io/robertashraf/pen/GmELJZ